# Is there any way I can customize this Content approval menu and delete/modify the sections I have Highlighted

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

[image: content approval menu]

I am trying to customize the inbuilt content approval process I tried using sharepoint designer but couldnt create a direct link to the approval form.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could customize the approve.aspx in SharePoint online.